# Why does the notification email claim the Stack Exchange Android app will send me notifications when it doesn't?

Tags: bug, android-app

[image]

I have the app installed on my Android device. It's logged in and I can manually open it and look at my inbox in the right hand pull out.

However, I can't remember the last time I've ever received a notification for the app on my Android device. They only seem to work for the iOS app. It's been this way for at least a couple of years across multiple phones.

Comment: The Stack Overflow app or the Stack Exchange app? The only reason I have the 
 Stack Exchange app installed on my Android phone is the notification functionality and it works fine for me...

Comment: @JonClements Stack Exchange-1.0.95

Comment: Yup... got 1.0.95 as well... and I  got notified of your comment here just fine...

Comment: You've double checked you've got "Allow Notifications" under Settings ticked ?

Comment: @JonClements I have allow notifications: https://i.imgur.com/e3IACie.jpg your comments notify fine on the iOS version of the app but just don't show up as notifications on Android.

Comment: Could be the iOS pushes get seen quicker so the Android device never gets anything pushed - same kind of thing that happens when you read your notifications on the site - it removes the notification in the app. I

Comment: @JonClements I can see that when I read the notifs on the site it withdraws the iOS notifications. But the Android never appears even when the iOS notifications stay around—so I’ve definitely given it time to deliver and show on my Android device before reading them elsewhere.

Comment: @JonClements You can see iOS withdraw your comment in response to me clicking on the notif on desktop 13 minutes after you replied to me [here](https://youtu.be/59G67ScRYLw). In all that time, I never saw the notification appear on my Android device.

Comment: My Android device is showing the SE notifications

Comment: My Android device has shown me notifications most of the time, but recently I noticed that it did not. Assuming it's not a newly introduced bug, it might have to do with whether the Android OS is still running the app in the background or not (?)

Comment: @lucidbrot If it’s using a standard push notification service, it shouldn’t require the application to be running in the background. Push should be able to launch apps.

Comment: Log out and back in again (in the app). It gets wedged sometimes.